# Cannot find eth1 interface

Tags: 12.04, networking, ethernet, interface

I installed **ubuntu precise** on my **IBM x3100** server and cannot find eth1 on my interfaces file.

Any clue what should I do?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think you should have a `/dev/eth1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
ifconfig -a
```

or:

```
sudo ifconfig -a
```

or, again:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0
sudo ifconfig eth1
```

Comment: Yes and I tries ** lshw -C network**, **dmesg | grep eth1**, and **sudo ifup eth1**
It said that eth1 isn't at the /etc/network/interfaces, so I appended the below to it and restart the networking.. all is O.K. now. thank you.
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp